# Axis2 web service & ports resolution

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

Our app seems to have stuck in a peculiar issue where the port number resolution in the `soap:address` is causing connectivity issues. Below is detailed explanation.

App setup:
1. Ours is a simple web service developed using axis2 in the traditional aar setup using Axis container.
2. Later it has been modified to use Tomcat container still with axis2 service. So the aar file has been deployed on the WEB-INF folder structure and reference to axis container has been removed. 
3. port numbers have been removed from the axis2.xml so as to allow the service be reached on the Tomcat ports. 
4. When the war is deployed, the folder structure is exploded and wsdl is generated with the `soap:address` as this:

```
wsdl:service name="XYZ">
<wsdl:port name="XYZHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="axis2:XYZSoap12Binding">
<soap12:address location="https://<big-ip>/<root-handle>/services/XYZ.XYZHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="XYZHttpEndpoint" binding="axis2:XYZHttpBinding">
<http:address location="https://<big-ip>/<root-handle>/services/XYZ.XYZHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="XYZHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="axis2:XYZSoap11Binding">
<soap:address location="https://<big-ip>/<root-handle>/services/XYZ.XYZHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

However, port number is being appended on the `soap:address` randomly which seems to be causing connectivity issues for the client.

Can anyone point me to what is wrong here?

Appreciate quick responses.

Comment: The issue is still not fixed but we found a temporary solution. We had to add "httpFrontendHostUrl" parameter on axis2.xml & had to maintain one axis2.xml for every environment i.e., one each for dit, sit, uat, prod which doesnt look correct to me.